Prefer pip to install from private GitLab package registry, and then fall back to PyPi
I am self hosting custom python packages on a local GitLab server and can pip install <custom_package> into Docker containers within CI/CD jobs or production environments. To achieve this I have added to the following to my ~/.config/pip/pip.conf file:
[global]
extra-index-url = https://<token_name>:<token_value>@<local_GitLab_server>/gitlab/api/v4/groups/<group_name>/-/packages/pypi/simple
trusted-host = <local_GitLab_server>

so far nothing unusual...
However, I created a package which has the same name as one already on PyPi and now when I do pip install <custom_package> I am installing from PyPi and not my local GitLab server.
Does anyone know how I can prefer GitLab over PyPi when the name appears twice?
I have found two work arounds, which are not ideal:

Give my custom packages a very unusual name which doesn't collide with PyPi, for example adding institution name before package. Not ideal as I then have very long package names.
Start my custom packages with a very high version number, which ensures that mine are chosen first (I checked this and it does work). However, given the trend to rapidly increase version numbers (e.g. Google Chrome is presently on version 123.0.6312.86), to be certain I would probably have to start with version 1000.0.1 which does look a little silly.


"Does anyone know how I can prefer one index over another when the name appears twice?" Nope, no way. pip doesn't prioritize indices, it downloads whatever it founds first.

You might also be interested in the provisional PEP 708: https://peps.python.org/pep-0708/ -- It is provisional, so that means not accepted nor implemented yet, but it is the most concrete effort that has been done in this direction so far. -- Otherwise, I recommend using your own index, or even a very simple solution perfect for your use case is simpleindex.

I figured out if you set index-url to GitLab, then you can use GitLab to pass through to PyPi.
What happens now is GitLab checks it's own package registry for the package, if it doesn't exist it will then search PyPi.
Note, you need to have PyPi forwarding enabled within GitLab's settings
